# await a promise without async function

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am writing a project in nodejs with express. In my app.js I noticed that I use an await without any async function. It works, but I don't know why.
Only valid if a file exists, otherwise I create it. And that's where I use the await
Here is my code:

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const app = express();

const filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const dirname = path.dirname(filename);
const filePath = path.join(dirname, "../files/products.json");
const exist = fs.existsSync(filePath);
if (!exist) await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify([]));
```

I would like someone to explain it to me.

Comment: First line of the [await documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)... _"It can only be used inside an async function or **at the top level of a module**"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top level await can be used if your package is a module (`"type": "module"` in your package.json or a `.mjs` file extension)

https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await

Comment: Thank you very much Phill !!! As always, reading the documentation is the answer.